# Change the button alignment in the steper flutter & Go back the steps using the button in appbar

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

1. I want to align the button at the bottom of the page and ***Fixed*** it without going up and down when the content changes
2. The second question is how to go back the steps using the arrow in the AppBar

[image]

```
Stepper(
controlsBuilder: (context, details) => Row(
                     children: [
                       Padding(
                         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 200.0),
                         child: ElevatedButton(
                             style: ButtonStyle(
                                 shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                         bottomLeft: Radius.circular(17),
                                         bottomRight: Radius.circular(17),
                                         topLeft: Radius.circular(17),
                                         topRight: Radius.circular(0)))

                                 ),
                                 backgroundColor:
                                 MaterialStateProperty.all(JobberColor().appColor)),
                             onPressed: details.onStepContinue,
                             child: Container(
                               alignment: Alignment.center,
                                 margin:
                                 const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 140, vertical: 20),
                                 child: const Text(
                                   'Next',
                                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                 ))),
                       ),


                     ],
                    ),
                    type: StepperType.horizontal,
                    physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                    currentStep: _currentStep,
                    onStepTapped: (step) {
                      tapped(step);

                    },
                    onStepContinue:  continued,
                    onStepCancel: cancel,
                    steps: <Step>[
                      Step(),
                      Step(),
                      Step(),
```

Comment: could you add you full code of this screen? your code only contains Stepper part

Comment: where are you using thus? can you include full sample widget

Answer (score 1):

You can using stack for positioned the button to the bottom of screen like this:

```
Stack(
    children: [
      Padding(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom:you button height),
         child: Stepper(
               controlsBuilder:...
         ),
      ),
      Positioned(left: 0,right: 0, bottom: 16,child: your button widget),
    ],
  ),
```

**for your second issue** you can check for `_currentStep` and if it is not equal to first step try to reduce `_currentStep` and if it is `pop` to previous page, like this:

```
AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.chevron_left),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_currentStep != 0) {
              tapped(_currentStep--);
            } else {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            }
          },
        ),
      )
```

Comment: may I ask, where is the tapped on tapped(_currentStep) come from

Comment: @fairycatto I didn't understand your question, can you explain more? `tapped(_currentStep)` was a function that questioner show in their code.